# Fatal error: 'YogaKit.modulemap' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile

I am developing a react native app which was working perfectly fine until now. I am repeadtely getting this error when I run 'yarn ios' from my terminal:

fatal error: module map file

```
'/Users/rutvishah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/radicalcashierapp-faqbvrdvmaacnvakysqpaudxmrvp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/radicalcashierapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
```

I am unable to build the app through terminal, but I can build the app successfully from xcode by opening .xcworkspace.

I have tried deleting the DerivedData folder, cleaning the build folder, removing node_modules, yarn.lock and Pods/, podfile.lock and rebuilding everything again. Nothing seems to work.

I am using:

```
xcode 14.2
node 18.19.0
cocoapods: 1.12.1
react-native: 0.72.7
```

I also tried reverting back to an older working commit, but the issue persist so my assumption is that something changed in the xcode settings that is causing this issue.

I have also tried following solutions from similar stackoverflow questions but that has also not helped

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Some more information about the environment:
npx react-native info

info Fetching system and libraries information...

```
System:
  OS: macOS 13.0
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
  Memory: 51.34 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: 5.8.1
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:

Node:
    version: 18.19.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/node

Yarn:
    version: 1.22.19
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.1/bin/yarn

npm:
    version: 10.2.3
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/npm

Watchman:
    version: 2023.12.04.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman

Managers:

CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: /Users/rutvishah/.rbenv/shims/pod

SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 22.2
      - iOS 16.2
      - macOS 13.1
      - tvOS 16.1
      - watchOS 9.1
  Android SDK: Not Found

IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996
  Xcode:
    version: 14.2/14C18
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild

Languages:
  Java:
    version: 11.0.11
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 3.1.2
    path: /Users/rutvishah/.rbenv/shims/ruby

npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.7
    wanted: 0.72.7
  react-native-macos: Not Found

npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found

Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false

iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```